# std stringstream bug on clang compiler: can not extract string to pointer;

Tags: c++, pointers, clang, stringstream

here sample code how to get this error on compiler clang

```
std::stringstream sstream;
int val = 10;
sstream << static_cast<void*>(&val); //"0x7fff5fbff94c"
void* ptr = nullptr;
sstream >> ptr; //0x7fff5
bool match = ptr == &val; //false
auto status = sstream.rdstate(); // 2- failbit
```

this error occur only on Clang compiler:
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wLwz0B1MDn2qDMId

can i do something wrong or this is a really clang bug?

Comment: Looks more like a bug in libc++ to me. Works fine in clang++3.8 (which includes a more recent libc++, I believe)